# The Grassmann twist-map, an associated semi-group action, and RSK

Tags: co.combinatorics, young-tableaux, cluster-algebras, total-positivity, robinson-schensted-knuth

Let me begin by setting some notation: Let $\mathrm{Mat}_{k,n}(\Bbb{R})$ denote the vector space of all $k \times n$
real-valued matrices. Given $g \in \mathrm{Mat}_{k,n}(\Bbb{R})$ and two (ordered) subsets $I = \{i_1 < \cdots < i_\ell \}$ and $J= \{j_1 < \cdots < j_\ell \}$ respectively taken from $\{1, \dots, k \}$ and $\{1, \dots , n\}$ let
$\Delta^{J}_I(g)$ denote the matrix minor of $g$ with row and column sets indexed respectively by $I$ and $J$. For brevity's sake we'll write $\Delta^J(g)$ instead of $\Delta_I^J(g)$ when $I = \{1, \dots, k\}$.

We'll say that a matrix $g \in \mathrm{Mat}_{k,n}(\Bbb{R})$
is *totally non-negative* (TNN for short) if **all** of its matrix minors $\Delta^J_I(g)$ are non-negative. Furthermore,
in the case that $k \leq n$, we'll say that a matrix $g \in \mathrm{Mat}_{k,n}(\Bbb{R})$
is *Grassmann totally non-negative* (GTNN for short) if all of its **maximal** minors $\Delta^J(g)$ are non-negative; where $J$ varies over all $k$-element subsets of $\{1, \dots, n\}$.

Assume $k < n$ and set $m = n - k$. Introduce the $k \times k$ *anti-diagonal* matrix $\Lambda$ whose entries $\lambda_{i,j}$ are given by

\begin{equation}
\lambda_{i,j} \, :=
\, \left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
\big( \! -1 \big)^{i-1} &\text{if $i+j=k$} \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

Given $g \in \mathrm{Mat}_{k,m}(\Bbb{R})$ define
an associated $k \times n$ matrix (written in block-form)
$F(g):= \big( \Lambda \, \big| \, g \big)$. The map
converts matrix minors of $g$ (of arbitrary size) into maximal
minors of $F(g)$. Specifically

\begin{equation}
\Delta_I^J (g) \, = \,
\Delta^{\tau(I)^c \, \cup \,  J + k} \big(F(g) \big)
\end{equation}

where $\tau$ is the bijection $i \stackrel{\tau}{\mapsto} k+1 -i$ for $i \in \{1, \dots, k \}$
and where
$J + k := \big\{j +k \, \|  \, j \in J \big\}$
is an index shift by $k$. Likewise, given
$g \in  \mathrm{Mat}_{k,n}(\Bbb{R})$ define $E(g)$ to be the $k \times m$ matrix whose entries are given by $g$'s maximal minors, namely

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle \big( E(g) \big)_{i,j} \, := \,
\Delta^{ \{ 1 \, \dots \, \widehat{\tau(i)} \, \dots \,  k \} \, \cup \, \{i + k\}  }
\end{equation}

Here $\widehat{\tau(i)}$ indicates that $\tau(i)$ is omitted. The reader can check, more generally, that

\begin{equation}
\Delta^J_I \big(E(g) \big) \, = \,
\Big( \Delta^{\{1, \dots, k\}}(g) \Big)^{\ell-1} \Delta^{\tau(I)^c \, \cup \,  J + k}(g)
\end{equation}

where $I$ and $J$ are $\ell$-element subsets of $\{ 1, \dots, k \}$ and $\{1, \dots , m \}$ respectively. It follows immediately from the these maximal minor formulae for the maps $E$ and $F$ that: $g \in \mathrm{Mat}_{k,m}(\Bbb{R})$ is TNN iff $F(g)$ is GTNN and $g \in \mathrm{Mat}_{k,n}(\Bbb{R})$ is GTNN iff
$F(g)$ is TNN.

Finally, let $\overleftarrow{g}$ denote the Marsh-Scott *twist* of the matrix
$g \in \mathrm{Mat}_{k,n}(\Bbb{R})$. The map is essentially an exportation of the Berenstein-Fomin-Zelevinsky twist to the (affine cone of) Grassmannian. In their paper (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.6630) the authors in effect offer four distinct but equivalent definitions of this map --- the simplest is presented in terms of consecutive, higher cross-products (I refer the reader to page 5 of their paper). For example, when $k = 3$ and $g \in \mathrm{Mat}_{3,n}(\Bbb{R})$
the twist map (at the level of matrices) is

\begin{equation}
\overleftarrow{g} \, := \, \Big( g_{n-1} \! \times g_n \ \
g_n \! \times g_1 \ \ g_2 \times g_3 \ \
\cdots \ \ g_{n-2} \! \times g_{n-1} \Big)
\end{equation}

where $g_1, \dots, g_n$ are the columns of $g$. A key feature of the twist is that $g$ is GTNN if and only if $\overleftarrow{g}$ is GTNN. Let us now compose these three maps
and define

\begin{equation}
T:  \mathrm{Mat}_{k,m}(\Bbb{R})
\longrightarrow  \mathrm{Mat}_{k,m}(\Bbb{R})
\quad T(g) \, := \, E\Big( \overleftarrow{F(g)} \Big)
\end{equation}

In view of the remarks made so far, $g$ is TNN if and only if
$T(g)$ is TNN. Furthermore $T(g)$ is an **integer** $k \times m$
whenever $g$ is. So we get a semi-group action $g \mapsto T(g)$
on the set $\mathrm{Mat}_{k,m}^{\scriptscriptstyle \mathrm{TNN}}(\Bbb{Z})$ of all integer TNN $k \times m$ matrices.

By the RSK-correpondence we know that the set $\mathrm{Mat}_{k,m}(\Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0})$ of all $\Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$-valued $k \times m$ matrices
is in bijection with the set of all pairs $P \times Q$ of
semi-standard tableaux (of the same shape) where the content
of $P$ is taken from $\{1, \dots, k\}$ and the content
of $Q$ is taken from $\{1, \dots, m \}$. This tableaux data
can be, in turn, converted into a *Gelfand-Tsetlin pattern*,
i.e. a $\Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$-valued $k \times m$ matrices
whose rows and columns are weakly increasing; call the latter set $\mathrm{GT}_{k,m}$. There are numerous places to learn about these bijections, but let me point the reader's attention
to the recent paper of Brubaker-Frieden-Pylyavskyy-Scrimshaw
(see https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.00524?context=math.RT).

**First Question:** Is there anything special about the pair of semi-standard tableaux $P \times Q$ (or the associated $\mathrm{GT}_{k,m}$ matrix) which corresponds to a TNN matrix
$ g \in \mathrm{Mat}_{k,m}^{\scriptscriptstyle \mathrm{TNN}}(\Bbb{Z})$ ?

**Second Question:** We can export the semi-group action
$g \mapsto T(g)$ to the image of $\mathrm{Mat}_{k,m}^{\scriptscriptstyle \mathrm{TNN}}(\Bbb{Z})$
under RSK. What is this action doing to pairs of semi-standard tableaux? What is it doing to the associated $\mathrm{GT}_{k,m}$ matrices?

thanks, ines.

Comment: Hmm, interesting question, but I have never seen anything about how to interpret even the determinant of the input matrix in terms of the output of RSK.